# Python not recognized in CMD

Tags: python, windows

I am working in Windows 11, Python 3.10, Mu 1.1.0. I followed the instructions on ATBS to create a batch file to run a script from the WIN + R launcher. However in CMD the error A(below) pops up. I tried following instructions from the documentation on python.org, and in Appendix B of ATBS to edit environment variables. I added the following to PATH env variables: C:\Users\19139\MyPythonScript; C:\Users\19139\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.10\Python 3.10 (64-bit).lnk; and C:\Users\19139\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.10\Python 3.10 (64-bit).lnk\Scripts. **Is there some issue with the fact that the PATH includes start menu?** All I am able to call from CMD is py --version. When I try and directly call a python script I get Error B. I disabled the "App Installer"(s) under App Aliases for Python.exe and Python3.exe but no change in error. I can call py --version, but I am beyond the scope of my ability to figure out what to do. **I am unsure of next possible step to problem solve, suggestions welcome.**

Error A:

```
`enter code here`Python path configuration:
PYTHONHOME = (not set)
PYTHONPATH = (not set)
program name = 'C:\Users\19139\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe'
isolated = 0
environment = 1
user site = 1
import site = 1
sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Users\\19139\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python.exe'
sys.base_prefix = ''
sys.base_exec_prefix = ''
sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
sys.executable = 'C:\\Users\\19139\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python.exe'
sys.prefix = ''
sys.exec_prefix = ''
sys.path = [
'C:\\Users\\19139\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python310.zip',
'C:\\Users\\19139\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\Lib\\',
'C:\\Users\\19139\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\DLLs\\',
'C:\\Users\\19139\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310',
]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\19139\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'codecs'
```

Error B

```
C:\Users\19139>python "C:\Users\19139\MyPythonScript\mClip.py"
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or 
disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, unlike ubuntu/ linux Windows doesn't detect python on its own. That's why we need to specify the path manually, to make it aware of python.

> Is there some issue with the fact that the PATH includes start menu?

Yes, there is issue there. PATH for python doesn't include Start Menu generally.
You are looking at the wrong place or have installed python package at the wrong location. Find the correct python package location.

Python PATH looks something like this:
 `C:\Users\user_name\python_installerpkg_name`

For example, if you have installed python using a python installer pkg like anaconda/ mini-conda, you can use its command prompt to find the location via `where python`. Then use the location to set the PATH in environment variables. the PATH would look like: `C:\Users\user_name\anaconda`

> Error B

Until you configure the correct path in the environment variables you won't be able to use the command `python filename.py` from the command line.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Reinstalled Python and chose the option: Add to Path. This has made cmd recognize python now and I am able to run the batch file.

Comment: Great, you got it working yourself! Modifying the PATH instead of reinstalling everything would have been easier. Anyways, if you found the answer helpful, do consider upvoting, accepting it.